# SAPUI5 Googlemaps library : multiple directions via list

Tags: sapui5

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/43ape.png)

```
                                <openui5.googlemaps:Waypoint id = "waypoint" location="{location}"/>
                                <!--<openui5.googlemaps:Waypoint location="Talod"/>-->
                            </openui5.googlemaps:waypoints>
                        </openui5.googlemaps:Directions>
                    </openui5.googlemaps:directions>
                </openui5.googlemaps:Map>
                <Input id="start" value="{start}" width="180px" placeholder="Start Address">
                    <layoutData>
                        <FlexItemData growFactor="2"/>
                    </layoutData>
                </Input>
                <Input id="end" value="{end}" width="180px" placeholder="End Address">
                    <layoutData>
                        <FlexItemData growFactor="2"/>
                    </layoutData>
                </Input>
                <Button text="Find distance" type="Emphasized" width="170px" press="go"></Button>
            </content>
        </Page>
    </pages>
</App>
```

Above code is of the view.I am adding code of controller but could not able to add it.I am having desired result for one start and end address but I could not able to have multiple lines for start and end address on same map.I need multiple lines with pin points as shown in image.

Comment: What have you already tried? Can you provide any code you've written in an attempt to achieve the result you want?

Comment: That doesn't actually answer my question.

Comment: Please put your code in your question (using the `edit` button) rather than in the comments.

Comment: @ular-sharma interesting use case, can you share a simple example on jsbin or equiv and i wll see if i can get it working .. ps im author of that library

Comment: Pleasure to have your reply.Thank you very much for awesome library.

This issue has been resolved now.

I have added one more question to that ink of scn.sap.


http://scn.sap.com/community/developer-center/front-end/blog/2014/07/01/google-maps-library-for-ui5